# Devnet CPI "unknown program" and "An account required by the instruction is missing"

Tags: anchor, cpi, invoke

Testing CPI calls on devnet (e.g. programs both deployed to devnet, anchor.toml set to devnet) yields this error:

```
 'Unknown program Ev6JrN5HqrKwXhoB9jucLdn51yzzDvWmBHkubXWavRio',
    'Program <theCpiCaller> consumed 27039 of 200000 compute units',
    'Program <theCpiCaller> failed: An account required by the instruction is missing'
```

Where the CPI gets invoked like this:

```
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct DummyMsgCpi<'info> {
    /// CHECK: Checked by dummy program
    pub dummy_acc: UncheckedAccount<'info>,
}

pub fn handler(ctx: Context<DummyMsgCpi>) -> Result<()> {
    let program_id: Pubkey =
        Pubkey::from_str("Ev6JrN5HqrKwXhoB9jucLdn51yzzDvWmBHkubXWavRio").unwrap();
    invoke(
        &Instruction {
            program_id,
            accounts: vec![AccountMeta::new_readonly(
                ctx.accounts.dummy_acc.key(),
                false,
            )],
            data: get_function_hash("global", "msg").to_vec(),
        },
        &[ctx.accounts.dummy_acc.to_account_info()],
    )?;
    Ok(())
}

pub fn get_function_hash(namespace: &str, name: &str) -> [u8; 8] {
    let preimage = format!("{}:{}", namespace, name);

    let mut hash = [0u8; 8];
    hash.copy_from_slice(
        &anchor_lang::solana_program::hash::hash(preimage.as_bytes()).to_bytes()
            [..8],
    );
    hash
}
```

And program `Ev6JrN5HqrKwXhoB9jucLdn51yzzDvWmBHkubXWavRio` looks like this for reference:

```
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Msg<'info> {
    /// CHECK: no security
    pub dummy_acc: UncheckedAccount<'info>,
}

pub fn handler(ctx: Context<Msg>) -> Result<()> {
    msg!("You sent: {:?}", ctx.accounts.dummy_acc.key());
    Ok(())
}
```

Best guess is that's a problem generating the correct discriminator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The program ID for the dummy program should be included in the `Accounts` struct, don't think you can build a CPI that tries to use a hardcoded pubkey as one required accounts for the CPI within the program itself

For example:

```
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct DummyMsgCpi<'info> {
    /// CHECK: Checked by dummy program
    pub dummy_acc: UncheckedAccount<'info>,
    /// CHECK: provide dummy program ID here
    pub program_id: UncheckedAccount<'info>,
}
```

And then within the instruction:

```
program_id: ctx.accounts.program_id.key()
```

You may also need to make changes to how you built your CPI.

This repo as good references for building CPIs for both native and anchor:
https://github.com/solana-developers/program-examples/tree/main/basics/cross-program-invocation

Comment: This is correct. Also have to add the key to account info when passing it to invoke, e.g: &[ctx.accounts.dummy_acc.to_account_info(), ctx.accounts.dummy_program.to_account_info()],

Answer (score 1):

Full solution:

```
pub const DUMMY_PROGRAM_KEY: &str = "Ev6JrN5HqrKwXhoB9jucLdn51yzzDvWmBHkubXWavRio";

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct DummyMsgCpi<'info> {
    /// CHECK: Checked by dummy program
    pub dummy_acc: UncheckedAccount<'info>,
    /// CHECK: Validated by constraint
    #[account(
        address = Pubkey::from_str(DUMMY_PROGRAM_KEY).unwrap()
    )]
    pub dummy_program: UncheckedAccount<'info>, // <added
}

pub fn handler(ctx: Context<DummyMsgCpi>) -> Result<()> {
    let program_id: Pubkey =
        Pubkey::from_str(DUMMY_PROGRAM_KEY).unwrap();
    invoke(
        &Instruction {
            program_id: Pubkey::from_str(DUMMY_PROGRAM_KEY).unwrap(),
            accounts: vec![AccountMeta::new_readonly(
                ctx.accounts.dummy_acc.key(),
                false,
            )],
            data: get_function_hash("global", "msg").to_vec(),
        },
        &[
            ctx.accounts.dummy_acc.to_account_info(),
            ctx.accounts.dummy_program.to_account_info(), // <added
        ],
    )?;
    Ok(())
}
```